Unable to Listen to Laravel Reverb event using Laravel Echo on React/TypeScript Frontend
Reverb Version
1.4.3
Laravel Version
11.33.x
PHP Version
8.3.1
Reverb Port
8001
Laravel Port:
8080
React Port:
5173
authEndPoint:
http://localhost:8001/api/broadcasting/auth
Description
I am using React/TypeScript App front end with Laravel Echo installed and a separate app for Laravel backend (as api with) the url in this form: localhost:8080/api/...
Reverb connection was established, channels subscribed with no auth.
After sending events from the backend, I didn't receive it from the frontend. I tried both private and public channels. Reverb debug terminal shows no event sent just this:
Message Received ............................................................................................................. 768209586.877632325
1▕ {
2▕     "event": "pusher:ping",
3▕     "data": []
4▕ }
P.S.: I don't mind if anyone can provide a step by step guide on how to setup Laravel Reverb, Laravel Echo on React/TypeScript (Frontend) and Laravel Backend API
Steps To Reproduce
Installed Laravel Reverb on Laravel 11 App and Laravel Echo on React App.
created rule for private channel in ./routes/channels.php file
run php artisan reverb:start --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8001 --debug
create simple react typescript app with laravel Echo
npm run dev
try to listenToAll your private channel.

I have fixed the issue
